# Use Linq.Dynamic or Expressions to create an new anonymous object

Tags: linq, dynamic, casting, anonymous-types

I've the following code:

```
public class C
{
  public string Field {get; set;}
  public string Data {get; set;}
}

var x = new C { Field = "F", Data = "Data 1" };
var y = new C { Field = "G", Data = "Data 2" };
```

And I want to cast this to an anonymous object like:

```
var x_a = new { F = "Data 1" };
var y_a = new { G = "Data 2" };
```

Note that the property name (F or G) is the content, so this can change dynamically. I'm currently using the System.Linq.Dynamic 'Select' method for this:

```
public static object CastToAnonymous(this C source)
{
  var objects = new List<C>(new [] {source}).AsQueryable().Select("new (Data as " + source.Field + ")") as IEnumerable<object>;
  return objects.First();
}
```

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Besides the obligatory question *why* you want to do this (I really like to know), I don't think there's an *easier* way, since `System.Linq.Dynamic` already implements the expression parsing stuff for you, so your code is already a one-liner.

Comment: FYI, the objects you get from using `Select()` in the dynamic linq library are not compatible with the ones that the compiler generates.  Does it really need to be a typed anonymous object?  Why not just put it in a dynamic object?  Use an expando object or write a dynamic wrapper.

Comment: Why do you want to cast it to anonymous type with same fields? What do you want to do with it then?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov : Not the same fields, please note that field in the anonymous type has the name : "F" or "G" which is the string CONTENT from the original C-class.

Comment: FYI, Technically this is not a cast.

Comment: @Stef you did not answered what do you want to do with this anonymous type instance. How do you want to use it?

Comment: Hi @KirillBestemyanov, I need this to create the aggregate field in the Kendo UI Grid Grouping like this : "NumberOfEmployees": { "count": 2 } }

Comment: Couldn't you just place the values into a dictionary? You're making it harder than it needs to be IMHO.

Comment: Hi @JeffMercado, you are correct. I did not recognize it as a dictionary. Thanks !